# sql cross join and inner join together

Tags: sql

I searched the internet, and I cannot find any combination of `cross join` and `inner join`.

Please help me......

I have three tables.

```
1) dbo.Dates
2) dbo.UsersCa
3) dbo.InfoCa
```

I need to make a combination of those tables in order to show what the users did every day.

If there is no entry in the dbo.InfoCa table then null must display.

I tried the following code, but it is not working. Please help....

```
SELECT dbo.UsersCa.PMP ,
    dbo.UsersCa.UsName ,
    dbo.UsersCa.UsSurname ,
    dbo.UsersCa.[Position] ,
    dbo.Dates.DateCA ,
    NULL ,
    NULL ,
    NULL
FROM   dbo.UsersCa
    CROSS JOIN dbo.Dates
UNION ALL
SELECT dbo.UsersCa.PMP ,
    dbo.UsersCa.UsName ,
    dbo.UsersCa.UsSurname ,
    dbo.UsersCa.[Position] ,
    NULL ,
    dbo.InfoCa.IDUser ,
    dbo.InfoCa.IDCa ,
    dbo.InfoCa.Description
FROM   dbo.UsersCa ,
    dbo.Dates
    INNER JOIN dbo.InfoCa ON dbo.Dates.DateCA = dbo.InfoCa.DateField
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the query you want uses a `left outer join` after the `cross join`.

The `cross join` gets all combinations of users and days.  The `left outer join` then brings in the day-per-user information:

```
SELECT u.PMP, u.UsName, u.UsSurname, u.[Position], d.DateCA,
     ic.IDUser, ic.IDCa, ic.Description
FROM dbo.UsersCa u cross join
     dbo.Dates d left outer join
     dbo.InfoCa ic
     ON d.DateCA = ic.DateField and
        d.IDUser = ic.IdUser;
```

Comment: and don't forget to join `ic.IDUser` to whatever column it links on `dbo.UsersCa` on the `ON` clause. my best guess is `ON d.DateCA = i.DateField
    AND u.IDUser = i.IDUser`

Comment: Your query would also need a CASE statement on DateCA to match the second half of the union.

Comment: THX for the quic answer. Can you explane me what do you maen with the CASE statement.